# Wrong size on input fields in iOS CSS

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, mobile

I'm trying to test my website in an iPhone and the input fields seem to have a larger size, they appear wider in my iPhone.

I tried with the following CSS but it's not working:

```
.set-title-input input{
   width: 120px;
   background-image:url('../img/header-input.png');
   height: 30px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: 'thnk_grotesk_officeregular';
   color: #fff;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   -webkit-appearance: none !important;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0;
   border-radius:0;
   @include border-radius(0);
   outline: none;
   border: none;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

`width: 120px!important;`